# How to make nested list into rows and columns in a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested list of coordinates:

[image: Nested List]

I need my list to be in the format of rows and columns shown below (I think it is called a data frame), with its contents having the Pythagorean formula applied against each cells' column and row header:

[image: Data Frame]

What is the best approach in Python to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcty, this should solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(coor_house)
df['l2'] = np.sqrt((df[1].apply(lambda x :x[0])
                   -df[0].apply(lambda x :x[0]))**2
                   +(df[1].apply(lambda x :x[1])
                   -df[0].apply(lambda x :x[1]))**2)
```

This will create a dataframe where each column is a point and a column with the l2 norm of the difference.

I'm not very used to apply  a function to a whole dataframe, so I'm sure there is a better way.